# Float, Enum and weirdness in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have been baffled by this behavior

```
Prelude> [1, 3 .. 6]
[1,3,5]
Prelude> [1.0, 3.0 .. 6.0]
[1.0,3.0,5.0,7.0]
```

I've found in [Haskell 98 report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/basic.html) that

> For Float and Double, the semantics of the enumFrom family is given by
>   the rules for Int above, except that the list terminates when the
>   elements become greater than e3+i/2 for positive increment i, or when
>   they become less than e3+i/2 for negative i.

My question is: why is it so?

Comment: This is going to be all to do with floating-point rounding errors. In general, anytime you compare two floating-point values, you probably want a small error tolerance [which is proportional to the size of the numbers involved].

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid: right, though arguably, over-shooting by 1 is not OK under any sensible rounding-error tolerance! The real problem is that Haskell ranges are in principle a bit weird, in a way that's particularly obvious when you throw in in-exact types like floating-point numbers.

Comment: Yes, in this case the tolerance seems far away from rounding problems. The previous question, which I couldn't find before asking, has the discussion I wanted to read. Thanks, @leftaroundabout !

Comment: The issue is that `6.0` falls exactly in the middle of the "natural" steps `5.0,7.0`. If you stop at `5.0` you are stopping `1.0` earlier than the boundary, if you stop at `7.0` you are `1.0` after the boundary. The error is `1.0` in both cases.  You might argue that `5.0` is more natural, and I would agree, but it's tricky to find a "perfect" convention which fist all uses.